# IndexOutOfBoundsException in a snake like game

Tags: java

I am supposed to get the snake rectangles to go down the side of the screen. However it stays in place and when I run it, I also get a IndexOutOfBoundsException error. I believe it has something to do with the for loop in my Render.java file. Here is the code:

**LewisProject.java**

```
package lewisproject;

import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class LewisProject implements ActionListener {

    public Toolkit toolkit;

    public JFrame jframe;
    public Render render;
    public static LewisProject lewisproject;

    public Timer timer = new Timer(20, this);

    public ArrayList<Point> catParts = new ArrayList<>();

    //head is the position of the first cat and the mouse is what you need to get in order to get more cats. 
    public Point head, mouse;

    public Random random;

    public boolean over = false;

    public Dimension dim;
    public int ticks = 0, direction = DOWN, score, tailLength;

    public static final int UP = 0, DOWN = 1, LEFT = 2, RIGHT = 3, SCALE = 10;

    public LewisProject() {

        //Grabs the screen size
        dim = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
        toolkit = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
        jframe = new JFrame("Cat Assassin");
        jframe.setVisible(true);
        //Sets Size of screen
        jframe.setSize(800, 800);
        //Centers the JFrame to the middle of your screen
        jframe.setLocation(dim.width / 2 - jframe.getWidth() / 2, dim.height / 2 - jframe.getHeight() / 2);
        jframe.add(render = new Render());
        //Closes the JFrame when you hit X.
        jframe.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        head = new Point(0, 0);
        //Puts a mouse in a random area of the screen.
        mouse = new Point(dim.width / SCALE, dim.height / SCALE);
        random = new Random();
        timer.start();

    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        //re renders square 
        render.repaint();
        ticks++;
        //These if statements are self explanatory. They add the point through the x and y axis depending on what direction the cats are going. 
        if (ticks % 10 == 0 && head != null && over != true) {
            catParts.add(new Point(head.x, head.y));
            if (direction == UP) {
                if (head.y - 1 > 0) {
                    head = new Point(head.x, head.y - 1);
                } else {
                    over = true;
                }
            }
        }
        if (direction == DOWN) {
            if (head.y + 1 < dim.height / SCALE) {
                head = new Point(head.x, head.y + 1);
            }
        } else {
            over = true;
        }

        if (direction == LEFT) {
            if (head.x + 1 > 0) {
                head = new Point(head.x - 1, head.y);
            } else {
                over = true;
            }
        }

        if (direction == RIGHT) {
            if (head.x + 1 < dim.width / SCALE) {

                head = new Point(head.x + 1, head.y);
            } else {
                over = true;
            }
        }
        catParts.remove(0);
        head = catParts.get(catParts.size() - 1);
        if (mouse != null) {
            if (head.x == mouse.x && head.y == mouse.y) {
                score++;
                tailLength++;
                mouse.setLocation(dim.width / SCALE, dim.height / SCALE);
            }
        }
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        lewisproject = new LewisProject();
    }
}
```

**Render.java**

```
package lewisproject;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Point;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Render extends JPanel{
   //It's more of a light gray but whatever.
    public static Color white = new Color(15132390);

//used @Override to get the error to be quiet while I work.   
    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        //Calls the super class (JPanel) and paints graphics.
        super.paintComponent(g);
        //Sets the Color of Rectangle to black and sets dimensions
        g.setColor(white);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, 800, 800);
        LewisProject lewisproject = LewisProject.lewisproject;
        g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        for (Point point : lewisproject.catParts){

            g.fillRect(point.x * LewisProject.SCALE, point.y * LewisProject.SCALE, LewisProject.SCALE, LewisProject.SCALE);

        }
            g.fillRect(lewisproject.head.x * LewisProject.SCALE, lewisproject.head.y * LewisProject.SCALE, LewisProject.SCALE, LewisProject.SCALE);

    }
}
```

**The Error**

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
    at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:638)
    at java.util.ArrayList.remove(ArrayList.java:477)
    at lewisproject.LewisProject.actionPerformed(LewisProject.java:101)
    at javax.swing.Timer.fireActionPerformed(Timer.java:313)
    at javax.swing.Timer$DoPostEvent.run(Timer.java:245)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:744)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$400(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:697)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:691)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:714)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

I believe I get this error because the for loop in Render.java isn't ending properly. Does anyone have a good solution to this?

Comment: It seems unlikely that an IndexOutOfBounds error is caused by your for loop. More likely is the catParts.remove(0) statement  or the get statement immediately follwing as there seems to be no guarantee that catParts has at least 2 elements. Try adding an assertion before that statement to make sure there are elements before you try to remove one.

Comment: Well have you run the code in the debugger and examined the variables, etc?

Comment: Now that you've added the trace it's pretty clear that it's the remove statement. Your logic in that method makes no sense - why are you removing an element when there's no guarantee the list has elements?

Comment: I haven't used debugger mode before. What is the best way to use it to find a fix for this? @OldProgrammer

Comment: What IDE are you using?  They all have debuggers.  Writing this much code and not learning how to use a debugger will be detrimental to you.  Spend a few hours with your IDE's debugger.

Comment: @OldProgrammer I am using NetBeans. I am currently messing around with the debugger. What are the advantages of using this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to check the size of the catParts collection before trying to remove or get items:

```
if (!catParts.isEmpty()) {
    catParts.remove(0);
}
if (!catParts.isEmpty()) {
    head = catParts.get(catParts.size() - 1);
    if (mouse != null) {
        if (head.x == mouse.x && head.y == mouse.y) {
            score++;
            tailLength++;
            mouse.setLocation(dim.width / SCALE, dim.height / SCALE);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Great. A few things you should probably take a look at if you want to progress as a coder: unit testing (JUnit), debugging, assert statements. All of these would help you a lot in this and future projects.

Answer (score 0):

You may try this update:

```
if(!catParts.isEmpty()) {//<-- put a check before removing with index
    catParts.remove(0);
}
```